# What is recommended way to do a PostgreSQL database backup: pg_dump or pg_basebackup?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

There are two different tools in PostgreSQL server:

- `pg_dump`
- `pg_basebackup`

What is the difference between these tools?
Which one to use to create database backup?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) creates a *logical backup*, that is a series of SQL statements that, when executed, create a new database that is logically like the original one.

[`pg_basebackup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) creates a *physical backup*, that is a copy of the files that constitute the database cluster. You have to use recovery to make such a backup consistent.

The main differences are:

- `pg_dump` typically takes longer and creates a smaller backup.
- With `pg_dump` you can back up one database or parts of a database, while `pg_basebackup` always backs up the whole cluster.
- A backup created by `pg_dump` is complete, while you need WAL archives to restore a backup created with `pg_basebackup` (unless you used the default option `-X stream`, in which case the backup contains the WAL segments required to make the backup consistent).
- With a logical backup you can only restore the state of the database at backup time, while with a physical backup you can restore any point in time after the end of the backup, provided you archived the required WAL segments.
- You need `pg_basebackup` to create a standby server, `pg_dump` won't do.
- A dump taken with `pg_dump` can be restored on a database running on an arbitrary operating system, as long as the PostgreSQL version is equal or higher than the version of `pg_dump`. In contrast, a `pg_basebackup` can only be restored with the same database version and on the same platform as the original.

Comment: Why do I need WAL archives for a backup created by pg_basebackup? when as stated: "while pg_basebackup always backs up the whole cluster" ?

Comment: @beatrice Because the backup is not consistent - the files changed while they were copied.

Comment: can `pg_dump` and `pg_basebackup` running concurrently ? say I have crontab running pg_dump on the master at 1 am. I also have `pg_basebackup`, that pulls data from the master, run from the slave from 10 pm to  3 am. so the processes intersect at 1 am. is it "dangerous" ? thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: @padjee No, that's no dangerous. But both `pg_dump` and `pg_basebackup` will stress the server, so the performance of your normal workload may suffer.

Comment: May I use either backups to restore backup on other major PostgreSQL version?

Comment: I have added an answer to that.