# May I use basebackup + WAL files to restore database after major version upgrade?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

We are planning to migrate our database from v11 to v15. We have [configured WAL backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY).  Can we use these files to restore database on v15 PostgreSQL or must we do [dump/restore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653867/4632019)?

Comment: No, but you can use logical replication to move data to a different version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a file system level backup (`pg_basebackup` or similar) can only be restored on the same version and operating system as the original.

Your alternatives are `pg_dumpall`/restore, `pg_upgrade` or logical replication.

Answer (score 1):

You will restore what you backed up.  If your backup is of v11, you will get v11 restored, and then need to upgrade it again.

There is a ticklish situation between the [`pg_upgrade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) and the first [`pg_basebackup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) taken on v15.  You might have all the WAL files, but you won't have a base backup (of the correct version) on which to apply them.  So you need to take a new base backup right after the [`pg_upgrade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html), and that should be included as part of the downtime planning.